# Passing arguments to Scrapy spider while instantiated from a script

Tags: python, django, scrapy

I have a scrapy spider that is called from a celery task. Now I want to customize the start_urls=[] based on some DB values. I know that Scrapy accepts arguments from the shell but that does not work in this case.

I've tried passing the urls as arguments to the Spider constructor but didn't work:

```
# getting the arguments on the spider contructor
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    start_urls = []

def __init__(self, some_url, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MySpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.start_urls.append(some_url)

# running the spirder
process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(MySpider(some_url='www.google.com'))
```

On the terminal I see that the first call do get the 'www.google.com' url, but the next ones do not.

Comment: what do you mean by the "first one", and the "next ones"? it really looks like it could be working